# Issue with tsconfig in strict mode and Type (...) is not assignable to type (...)

Tags: typescript, types, multer, tsconfig

I know there are quite a lot of question about this, I did read most of them (I guess) and they helped me having a better understanding of this error, and how to solve it in most cases.

However I am facing one I could not resolves by myself, so apologies if SO is not the good place for this question (I guess this could be a dupe since there is already questions about this issue, but I did not found any that helped me to solve this "particular case").

I have the following piece of code :

```
import { Request } from 'express'
import multer from 'multer'
import path from 'path'

class ImageMiddleware {

    // ...

    private storage (folder: string): multer.StorageEngine {
        return multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (
                _req: Request,
                _file: Express.Multer.File,
                callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void
            ): void => {
                return callback(null, `./public/img/${folder}`)
            },
            filename: (
                req: Request,
                file: Express.Multer.File,
                callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void): void => {
                callback(
                    null,
                    `${file.fieldname}`
                    + `-`
                    + `${Date.now()}`
                    + `${req.user.id}`
                    + `${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
                )
            },
        })
    }

    // ...
}

export default new ImageMiddleware()
```

With this tsconfig.json :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowUnreachableCode": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": ["**/spec/*.spec.ts", "./node_modules"]
}
```

But when running `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc` I have the following error :

```
services/middlewares/image/image.middleware.ts:112:13 - error TS2322: Type '(_req: Request, _file: File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) => void' is not assignable to type 'string | ((req: Request, file: File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) => void) | undefined'.
  Type '(_req: Request, _file: File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) => void' is not assignable to type '(req: Request, file: File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) => void'.
    Types of parameters '_req' and 'req' are incompatible.
      Type 'Request' is missing the following properties from type 'Request': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 71 more.

112             destination: (
                ~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/multer/index.d.ts:59:9
    59         destination?: string | ((req: Express.Request, file: Express.Multer.File, callback: (error: Error | null, destination: string) => void) => void);
               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'destination' which is declared here on type 'DiskStorageOptions'
```

So I guess that the `): void => {` line is wrong, hence I tried a lot of stuff to debug it but did not find anything successfull.

The output of `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -v` is `Version 3.3.4000`

Any help would be welcome, please let me know if I forgot some relevant informations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this error is in node_modules the only hope of fixing it is a pull request to the typings repository.

For now to silence the error turn "skipLibCheck": true in tsconfig.

EDIT: Sorry misread where error was coming from.

"Types of parameters '_req' and 'req' are incompatible."
I Suspect if you're using express you've ended up with two types for "Request" there is one in the standard typescript library which 1 function is typed with and another type for "Request" that exists in express that express uses.

Comment: Well, I might be mistaken but I don't think the error is coming from the node_modules (I did not post the last version of tsconfig.json, apologies, but I have : `"exclude": ["**/spec/*.spec.ts", "./node_modules"]` I'll edit this in the question. Furthermore, the error is clearly on my file `services/middlewares/image/image.middleware.ts` at line 112 I think it's just a (nice) hint from typescript to tell me wich definition file to check. This file is in node_modules so it point to that. I did try `"skipLibCheck": true ` tho but the output is still the same

Comment: Oh sorry must have misread where the error was coming from, i'll edit

Comment: Also the fact that the node_modules error is slightly indented also seems to me that this just is typescrypt printing some stacktrace to help me, sadly I did not yet find how to put the right type for this particular definition :(

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Not sure how to load the right module tho. I load `import { Request } from 'express'` so if multer is using another type of Request how can I load it ? I tried something like `_req: Express.Multer.` but it only autocompletes to `Express.Multer.File`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Multer but Request is definitely the problem here the typeof Request is different across both types in terms of it's signature.

Comment: You were right, writing `Express.Request` instead of `Request` solved the issue. I don't understand why tho since I did `import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express'` at the top of the file so `Request` and `Express.Request` should be the same thing no ?